# Basic error when trying to run party's cforest

Tags: r, random-forest, party

Trying to run `R`'s `party` `package`'s `cforest` and doing something basically wrong.

Here's my example data:

```
set.seed(1)
pred.mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100)
colnames(pred.mat) <- paste("feature",1:10,sep="")
df <- cbind(data.frame(y=round(runif(100))),pred.mat)
```

Trying to run `cforest`:

```
library(party)
crf.fit <- cforest(y~.,data=df)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in mget(plabels[hasSubclass], env) : invalid first argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't reproduce - it works for me (party 1.0-25)

Comment: Can you test and confirm getting this error after updating R and party? If not, I'll probably vote to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works without problems for me in current versions of R and `party`. Moreover, the offending piece of code `mget(plabels[hasSubclass], env)` is *not* in the `party` package but it comes from the basic `methods` package which is used by `party`. My suspicion is that your installation is out of sync in some way, e.g., you did not re-install the packages in your library after upgrading your R version or something similar. So you could try to run `update.packages(..., checkBuilt = TRUE)` or something along those lines to reinstall the packages in your libraries. Hopefully, this should fix the issue above.

Another comment regarding your artificial example: The variable `y` is a numeric 0/1 dummy variable but I assume you really want to do classification rather than regression. So I would recommend to do

```
df$y <- factor(df$y)
```

prior to fitting the `cforest()`. This will assure that the appropriate test statistics are used during the learning of the tree - and the correct predictions are produced etc.